# I need return JSON as beauty table style

Tags: python, json, xml, python-requests, prettytable

I have this code and works well

```py
import requests 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

def get_stock(sku):
    params = {'ItemId': sku}
    base_url = 'http://10.0.0.25/api/GetSku'
    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    json_parsed = json.loads(response.content)
     
    if response.status_code == 200:
      return [item for item in response.json() if item['Site'] == "12"]
    else:
      return None

def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)
jprint(get_stock(101025HRLONDON))
```

The output is json:

```
[
   {
        "ItemId": "101025HRLONDON",
        "Site": "12",
        "Warehouse": "17",
        "availablePhysical": 1.0
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "101025HRLONDON",
        "Site": "12",
        "Warehouse": "33",
        "availablePhysical": 1.0
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "101025HRLONDON",
        "Site": "12",
        "Warehouse": "34",
        "availablePhysical": 1.0
    },
]
```

I need a way to convert the above output to beauty table or similar like this:

```
+----+------+----------------------+
| WH |aval. | ItemID               |
+----+------+----------------------+
| 17 |    1 | 101025HRLONDON       |
| 33 |    1 | 101025HRLONDON       |
| 34 |    1 | 101025HRLONDON       |
+----+------+----------------------+
```

Please share your experience working with something like this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both [PrettyTable](https://zetcode.com/python/prettytable/) and [BeautifulTable](https://pypi.org/project/beautifultable/).   You can pip install these and read the docs.  If you really want to make something useful, OpenpyXl is the way to go.